# Application-defined or object-defined error when executing code with a concatenated formula

Tags: excel, hyperlink, listobject, vba

In this code block, I am trying to replace the text in a table cell with a formula that has the cell's value appended to the end of the string, then make it a hyperlink using a common URL path. However, when I run this code, I receive the 'Application-defined or object-defined error on the ".DataBodyRange.Formula = concat" line. After this is resolved, I would like to create a button that executes this code for all cells in the .DataBodyRange (as a quick update for new text entries).

**EDIT 1:** @jamheadart's answer fixed this (**EDIT 2:** although I've just realised that the closing brackets were slightly off (included the second variable when it should only contain the first - URL) - code edited below.

**Next part of question:**
With the semantics fixed; how would i change the code within the below sub to iterate through all cells in .DataBodyRange? Currently, it sets all cells in DataBodyRange to equal the contents in cell E2, but I need it to use the unique value in each cell to generate the hyperlink. **EDIT 2:** solved this on my own - full code below. I changed the table format so that I only require the one column edited. This currently doesn't capture the case where rerunning the code will append the full URL to the end of the URL value string but is fixed with a simple if statement (if v does not contain 'HTTP', create the concat string and set a.Cell value to concat).

Thanks for your help!

```
Sub Hyperlinkify()
'
' Hyperlinkify Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+t
'
    Dim oSh As Worksheet
    Set oSh = ActiveSheet
    Dim v As String
    Dim concat As String
    Dim url As String
    url = "http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid="


    Dim RNG As Range
    Dim aCell As Range
    Set RNG = Sheets("MTG Basic Lands").ListObjects("tbl_mtg_lands").ListColumns("Card id").DataBodyRange
    For Each aCell In RNG.Cells
        ' if v contains 'http' (or doesnt start with a number, both work), run the following 3 lines of code:
        v = aCell.Value
        concat = "=HYPERLINK(""" & url & v & """, " & v & ")"
        aCell.Value = concat
    Next aCell
End Sub
```

[Screenshot of the End Product :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNwyd.png) (I don't have enough rep to post the image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need quotes around your HYPERLINK so the line

```
concat = "=HYPERLINK(" & url & v & ", " & v & ")"
```

Which results in `=HYPERLINK(http://...)`

Should be

```
concat = "=HYPERLINK(""" & url & v & ", " & v & """)"
```

To give `=HYPERLINK("http://...")`

After you pointed out the HYPERLINK() function has a second parameter for display text:

```
concat = "=HYPERLINK(""" & url & v & """, " & v & ")"
```

Comment: Thanks, jamheadart! This works :) It gets hella confusing quoting quotes lol. 

I'll edit the OP with this change. I still need to iterate through the table, however, and it needs to be dynamic as I may add/subtract columns over time. What is the most efficient way to iterate through each cell in a table?

Comment: just realised that you added the closing quotations after the display property of the hyperlink. 

The proper solution is:
 concat = "=HYPERLINK(""" & url & v & """, " & v & ")"

Comment: Ah yeah, well spotted! I only did a quick test on a hyperlink to make sure that any URL would correctly display - I didn't realise the comma was actually separating the 2nd parameter of the function. I will amend!

Answer (score 0):

Your forgot to include the double quotes.  Here is an example:

```
Sub MakeFormula()
    Dim v As String
    Dim concat As String
    Dim url As String
    Dim DQ As String

    DQ = Chr(34)

    v = Range("E2").Value
    url = "https://www.google.com/search?q="
    Range("E4").Formula = "=HYPERLINK(" & DQ & url & v & DQ & "," & DQ & v & DQ & ")"

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! I appreciate the CH() reference. However, using the quotation marks feels like a more elegant solution.